# DatastoreService I don't understand where does it save data?

Tags: google-app-engine

I have Datastore Class and I use this class to try GCM . I do not understand where the data is saved (registrations id) but I can retrive this after I restart my IDE (Eclipse)

Thanks friends

```
private static final DatastoreService datastore =
    DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();

private Datastore() {
  throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}

/**
 * Registers a device.
 *
 * @param regId device's registration id.
 */

public static void register(String regId) {
  logger.info("Registering " + regId);
  Transaction txn = datastore.beginTransaction();
  try {
    Entity entity = findDeviceByRegId(regId);
    if (entity != null) {
      logger.fine(regId + " is already registered; ignoring.");
      return;
    }
    entity = new Entity(DEVICE_TYPE);
    entity.setProperty(DEVICE_REG_ID_PROPERTY, regId);
    datastore.put(entity);
    txn.commit();
    } finally {
    if (txn.isActive()) {
      txn.rollback();
    }
  }
}

/**
 * Gets all registered devices.
 */

public static List<String> getDevices() {
  List<String> devices;
  Transaction txn = datastore.beginTransaction();
  try {
    Query query = new Query(DEVICE_TYPE);
    Iterable<Entity> entities =
        datastore.prepare(query).asIterable(DEFAULT_FETCH_OPTIONS);
    devices = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (Entity entity : entities) {
      String device = (String) entity.getProperty(DEVICE_REG_ID_PROPERTY);
      devices.add(device);
    }
    txn.commit();
  } finally {
    if (txn.isActive()) {
      txn.rollback();
    }
  }
  return devices;
}
```

Comment: The data is stored either in GAE datastore when you are in production servers, or in a local file when you are in local development environment. In any case, you can see what data is stored in your app from admin console. For the development environment, you can check at http://localhost:8080/_ah/admin

Comment: http://localhost:8888/_ah/admin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is stored either in GAE datastore when you are in production servers, or in a local file when you are in local development environment ( https://appengine.google.com/ --> application -->Datastore Indexes).
 In any case, you can see what data is stored in your app from admin console. For the development environment, you can check at

localhost:8888/_ah/admin (from your browser)